# Zabbix Performance tunning (with Proxies)

Tags: performance, proxy, zabbix

We setup a distributed monitoring cluster with one Zabbix (3.4.7) Server and 8 Proxies:

Zabbix:

```
OS: Debian Stretch
CPU: 16*2.27GHz
RAM: 48GB
Disk: Raid1 10K (Non-SSD)


LogFile=/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_server.log
PidFile=/var/run/zabbix/zabbix_server.pid
DBName=zabbix
DBUser=zabbix
DBHost=127.0.0.1
DBPort=3307
LogFileSize=0
DBPassword=****
Timeout=4
AlertScriptsPath=/etc/zabbix/alert.d/
FpingLocation=/usr/bin/fping
LogSlowQueries=3000
Include=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf.d/*.conf
StartAlerters=10
StartPollers=80
StartPollersUnreachable=80
StartTrappers=20
StartPingers=30
StartEscalators=5
CacheSize=8G
StartDBSyncers=16
HistoryCacheSize=2048M
TrendCacheSize=256M
ValueCacheSize=10G
HistoryIndexCacheSize=2G
ExternalScripts=/etc/zabbix/alert.d/
SSHKeyLocation=/nonexistent/.ssh
```

Proxy:

```
OS: Debian Stretch
CPU: 15*2.5GHz
RAM: 6GB
Disk: Raid1 10K (Non-SSD)


Server=XXXX
Hostname=zbx-lte
LogFile=/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_proxy.log
LogFileSize=0
PidFile=/var/run/zabbix/zabbix_proxy.pid
SocketDir=/var/run/zabbix
DBName=zabbix
DBUser=zabbix
DBPassword=159753
ConfigFrequency=600
DataSenderFrequency=1
StartPollers=240
StartPollersUnreachable=80
StartTrappers=20
StartPingers=80
SNMPTrapperFile=/var/log/snmptrap/snmptrap.log
CacheSize=1G
StartDBSyncers=16
HistoryCacheSize=2048M
HistoryIndexCacheSize=2G
Timeout=6
ExternalScripts=/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts
FpingLocation=/usr/bin/fping
LogSlowQueries=3000
```

We're monitoring near 1650 nodes (snmp, icmp, agent, ssh ,external scripts and external applications) by Zabbix

Since (about ) 2 month ago ,  we saw so many lags in non-icmp graphs  (Pic: 5.png) on specific zabbix proxy (zbx-lte in pics)

[image: too many lags on all graphs of Zabbix Proxy]
<sub>(source: [sassan.co](https://sassan.co/tmp/5.png))</sub>

this graph is related to a device (with snmp v2).  (there are many other graph like this on this proxy)
I capture network traffic of relevant zabbix proxy , For one of items  , zabbix proxy sends only 16 queries instead of 60 queries (with interval 1m for 1 hour) .

[image: too many lags on all graphs of Zabbix Proxy]
<sub>(source: [sassan.co](https://sassan.co/tmp/4.png))</sub>

If I change this device to monitor by Zabbix Server or any other proxies everything work properly

It sounds there is a problem on this proxy
[image: htop of Zabbix Proxy]
<sub>(source: [sassan.co](https://sassan.co/tmp/2.png))</sub>

[image: free mem of Zabbix Proxy]
<sub>(source: [sassan.co](https://sassan.co/tmp/6.png))</sub>

Please help me to find the root cause.

[image: More Details]
<sub>(source: [sassan.co](https://sassan.co/tmp/6.png))</sub>

[image: More Details]
<sub>(source: [sassan.co](https://sassan.co/tmp/zbx-1.png))</sub>

[image: More Details]
<sub>(source: [sassan.co](https://sassan.co/tmp/zbx-2.png))</sub>

[image: More Details]
[image: More Details]
<sub>(source: [sassan.co](https://sassan.co/tmp/zbx-4.png))</sub>

[image: More Details]
<sub>(source: [sassan.co](https://sassan.co/tmp/zbx-5.png))</sub>

[image: More Details]
<sub>(source: [sassan.co](https://sassan.co/tmp/iow.png))</sub>

Comment: Load average is quite high, considering the 16 CPUs. Could you check the iowait of the system and share a screenshot ?

Comment: @SimoneZabberoni

top screenshot added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

Surprisingly , The answer is very funny!

Server address in zabbix_proxy was an FQDN address , Our performance issues was solved when I add it to /etc/hosts.